# i am trying to update a column but i get some error

Tags: postgresql

```
update po_details_master
set isactive = True
```

```
ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function action_timestamp_column()
SQL state: 2F005
```

Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION action_timestamp_column() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    SET SCHEMA 'public'
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SET search_path = public
    AS '
    BEGIN
    END;
    ';

CREATE TRIGGER action_timestamp_column BEFORE UPDATE
    ON po_details_master FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
   action_timestamp_column();
```

Comment: Are there any trigger associated with this table.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger function is invalid. A trigger function **must** return something.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER)

> A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.
>   
>   Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row

So the minimal version of a trigger function that does nothing is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION action_timestamp_column() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  SET SCHEMA 'public'
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  SET search_path = public
AS $body$
BEGIN
  return new; --<< this is missing in your trigger and causes the error.
END;
$body$
;
```